# Форма и её обработка на php

Tags: php, html

У меня есть форма для загрузки одного файла,как можно сделать так чтобы загружались и обрабатывались сразу два??

```
<?php if(!empty($message)) { echo "<p>{$message}</p>"; } ?>
 <form action = "upload.php" enctype = "multipart/form-data" method = "POST">

  <input type = "hidden" name = "MAX_FILE_SIZE" value = "1000000000" />
  <input type = "file" name = "file_upload" />
  <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Upload" />
```

Проблема в том что когда я повторяю строчку

```
     <input type = "file" name = "file_upload" />
```

Мой php код начинает ругаться,подскажите как исправить

Comment: везде делать `name = "file_upload[]"`

Comment: А внутри скобок нужно что то писать?

Comment: Нет. это просто показывает, что будет массив элементов с таким именем. На сервере сделайте `print_r($_FILES);` и посмотрите что придет

Comment: Теперь ругается в этой части  кода

Comment: $tmp_file    = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
         $target_file = basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name']);
         $upload_dir  = "uploads";    А конкретно на basename

Comment: может просто писать: name = "file_upload2" ?

Comment: Пробовал не получилось

Comment: @pavel ну правильно ругается. я же написал что это **МАССИВ**. и специально сказал написать **`print_r($_FILES);`** или **`var_dump($_FILES);`** чтоб посмотреть что приходит. Или я это для себя написал?

Comment: Я написал, там  массив как вы и говорите,только я не понимаю как это в коде реализовать,теперь

Comment: @pavel А как работают с массивами? В цикле... `for ($i=0; $i <=count($_FILES); $i++) {
 echo $_FILES['file_upload']['name'][$i];
}`

Answer (score 1):

Называем поля для файлов именами file1, file2, file3...

А в скрипте просто пишем `foreach ($_FILES as $file) if (!$file['error'])...` .